# Dynamically load web-page content

Tags: javascript, ajax, vbscript, web

I have a web-page which content must be constructed on the fly. When user clicks some parts of the web-page, it must load information from the file which is placed on the server in the same directory along with web-page into special content `<div>`.

As far as I get it, with JavaScript, I must use ajax technology so I have a question: should I configure server so that he can handle ajax requests specifically, or is it just simple GET over HTTP request which should be supported by any web-server anyway?

And my second question - if ajax is technology, which will work out only if server is properly configurated, can I do what I need by simple GET from JavaScript somehow?

Also, if it is easier to use server-side scripting, how can it be done by VBScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX requests are very much like usual HTTP requests. So you do not need to configure your server in any special way to make them work.
A usual server should already support at least GET and POST requests.

One thing, that might be important for you, however, is, that as long as there is no other "protection" for the files, everyone can access them directly, too. So in case the AJAX-loaded content contains some kind of user sensitive data, you should put some access control in place!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX involves server side scripting, so it doesn't make sense to say it is easier to use server side scripting. Additionally, AJAX is nothing more than GET or POST requests that a script carries out for you asynchronously, allowing you to use the server responses in a document without reloading the entire page.

AJAX in and of itself is not so much of a technology as a technique. You can use AJAX, for example, without ever using the ubiquitous XmlHttpRequest object supplied by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

With the jQuery AJAX methods, you can request text, HTML, XML, or JSON from a remote server using both HTTP Get and HTTP Post - And you can load the external data directly into the selected HTML elements of your web page...

and yes, no configa server properly

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to you jquery framework (no server configure needed) (see also Sirko answer)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

this is help you to load dynamic content [see this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm)

Comment: Would you like to add an excerpt to your answer, so your answer will still be useful if the link dies?