# Simple Sidebar Navigation to populate main content

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, iframe

First, I know this is very simple and I'm as baffled as you are that I can't figure it out on my own. I have no background in web development and need to use github pages to document a project. I've been spinning my wheels on this for an embarrassing amount of time.

The crux of the problem is that I'm trying to use nested iframes, but with each layer I get another scroll bar and nothing scrolls quite in sync. If I set scrolling="no" content is hidden. This is exacerbated when I use a frames for the side bar.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="./styles/main_style_sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="mainheader"> 
    <b> My Project Name
    </b>
</div>

<body>

<div class="topnav">
    <a href="overview.html" target="main_body">Overview</a>
    <a href="important_concepts.html" target="main_body">Model Concepts/Patterns</a> 
    <a href="lineage.html" target="main_body">Data Lineage</a>
    <a href="entity_metadata.html" target="main_body">Entity Details</a>
    <a href="jargon.html" target="main_body">Jargon Glossary</a> 
    <a href="examples.html" target="main_body">Example Demos</a>             
</div>

<!-- This creates a frame in the lower body, with an unwanted scroll bar, but it's not too bad. --> 
<iframe name="main_body" src="overview.html" height="100%" width="100%">

</body>
</html>
```

It gets more problematic is trying to do the left sidebar. It looks like I just don't understand how heights are inherited between frames. The image shows how the sidebars keep stacking up, and the scrolling is just not quite in sync. I've tried bumping up the height to 100000 and hiding scrolling, but then horizontal scroll is also eliminated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <link href="./styles/main_style_sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    

  <body>

  <div class="container" style="display: flex; height:100%;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
      <iframe 
            src="cs_entity_sidebar.html"
            name="cs_entity_sidebar"
            frameborder="0" 
            scrolling="no" 
            width="100%" 
            align="left">
      </iframe> 

    </div>
      <iframe  class="second-row" 
          name="main_overview_content" 
          scrolling = "yes"
          height=10000 
          align="left"
        >
      </iframe>
</div>

</html>
```

[image: Extra scrolling]
This site has a tutorial that is almost what I need, just a simple layout without frames

https://usefulangle.com/post/61/html-page-with-left-sidebar-main-content-with-css

Operative snippet:

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Content Area</div>
</div>
```

But how to I get "Content Area" to populate with the linked html? When I try to do this in my own html is just brings me to a separate window without the top navigation.

This question also gets pretty close, but doesn't cover how to get the links and navigation working.

Furthermore, I have read the jquery/ajax is the better approach here, but none of what I'm doing in ajax has an effect. I'm on a corporate vpn so I'm thinking there is some proxy issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Jquery/Ajax approach which is not working. It doesn't fail, the click just doesn't do anything. I've tried various sources, including the google library, but src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" is what I've seen working on other projects in my company.

Note the screenshot, nothing loaded above "Above this is from the script"

```
<html>
<head>

  <!-- load ajax, file can also be loaded locally -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="./styles/main_style_sheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <script>
    /* create event handler that loads content into main area when navigation link is clicked */
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#link1').click(function(){
        $('#main_body').load('test.html');
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="mainheader"> 
    <h3>My Project Name</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a id="link1">Overview</a>            
  </div>

  <!-- where you want the page to load -->
  <div id="main_body"></div>
  <div>Above is loaded from script</div>
  <div>Below is loaded from a frame</div>
  <iframe src="test.html" ></iframe>  

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Not working as expected]

edit2: Inspect view error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are trying to make a website that lets users navigate to a new page without triggering a page refresh. This is a modern feature of dynamic websites.

For this purpose, it is definitely preferable to use jquery/ajax over iframe because of the many styling issues related to iframes (think about responsive mobile webpages). Here's a simple snippet for implementation using jquery/ajax

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>

  <!-- load ajax, file can also be loaded locally -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    /* create event handler that loads content into main area when navigation link is clicked */
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#link1').click(function(){
        $('#main_body').load('overview.html');
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="mainheader"> 
    <h3>My Project Name</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a id="link1">Overview</a>            
  </div>

  <!-- where you want the page to load -->
  <div id="main_body"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

overview.html:

```
<html>
<style>
  #wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
  }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Dynamically loaded webpage</p>
</div>
</html>
```

[image] [image]

[link to a demo](https://repl.it/repls/MicroStarchyOpendoc)

Note that there are some security concerns to consider when you dynamically load content. You can read more about this in this question: [Dynamic html page creation with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929587/dynamically-load-web-page-content)

Edit: Your code works fine on an online text editor. Ajax only works if you host the webpages on a server where the page can be loaded with supported protocol schemes such as http/https.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is almost identical to the approach I'd tried previously without success. I've added the code and screenshot to the question.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your console in inspector view, after you click on the link?

Comment: Added. Nice, I didn't think of that. At least I can see the error message now.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It's a simple issue of protocol schemes.

Comment: Woah. I'd read that language a dozen times but it just didn't click until seeing the error message. After running it through a local web server it works exactly as expected.